How to config resource for Java Spring Boot on Intellij
I have a Java project (using Gradle) with many modules. When I build and run on Esclipse, it works normally, but can not run on the Intellij. The error relates to the resource path, all the source code are created in src/main/java, the resources folder src/main/resources is not used. 
Please, help me to resolve this error. I would like to develop on Intellj instead of Esclipse.
The sample code:
FdcEquipmentInfo eqpModule = DbUtils.select(
                    DbUtils.toSqlPath(this.getClass(), "select_detail_equipment_module.sql"), queryParam,
                    FdcEquipmentInfo.class);

The package structure: 

The error message:
Couldn't find resource by classpath: .../get_detail/select_detail_equipment_module.sql


Non java sources should go in src/main/resources as those will be ignored if placed in src/main/java.
